# How can I make dokuwiki shown as PC mode not mobile mode?

Tags: dokuwiki

I have installed `dokuwiki` to my server.
It shows in mobile mode when I access to it with Android or iPhone.
But I want to show it as PC mode.
How can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dokuwiki's API let determine if the client [is mobile](https://github.com/splitbrain/dokuwiki/blob/master/inc/common.php#L663). Then it's up to the template to use this information or not.

You could try `grep -rn ismobile .` on your template code to see how it is used.

Ideally I would have added a comment to ask which template you use, but I'm afraid I don't have enough reputation to leave comments yet.

Comment: Thanks for an advice. So what exactly I can do to make my dokuwiki PC style even when it's seen by mobile?

Comment: I'm not sure there's an official and clean way. You could try to edit Dokuwiki itself to make the [clientismobile](https://github.com/splitbrain/dokuwiki/blob/master/inc/common.php#L663) function always return true.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to switch all the false to true in that function. I did the opposite too. But it seemed no cahnge:(

Comment: Why has this answer been accepted if it didn't solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Which template are you using?

If it's the default "dokuwiki" template, simply remove the line with `css/mobile.css` from the `style.ini` file in `./lib/tpl/dokuwiki/`.